# SSRS Null to Zero in Chart

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Trying to show the full category group for a chart in Report Builder, but it's missing category values where there is a null return using a count function (ie. trying to count to show # of documents in a users queue)

In charts, how can I make ALL category values show on the axis, even where there is a null return.

Using Report Builder 2008.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UserName, SUM(Documents) AS Documents
FROM (
    SELECT UserName, 1 AS Documents
    FROM Documents
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UserName, 0 AS Documents
    FROM Users
)
```

Comment: Is there a way to handle this via report builder chart settings instead of at the query level?

Comment: You can't report on data you don't have